# Apple developers rejected- subscriptions to be used in the app - Business - 3.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

Apple developers rejected my app with this reason.

"Business - 3.1.1
Your app includes an account registration feature, which is considered an access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app.
This feature does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Next Steps
Please remove the account registration links and any other fully qualified links to your site that could indirectly provide access to these mechanisms, such as links to web pages for support, FAQ, product or program details, etc."

The users can use the app in demo mode (without registration) with some restrictions, but if they register they can use without registrations.
The registration is not in webview. The client sends the user's datas to server.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can present a login screen in the app, but you cannot provide any details about how they register or a link to the web page where they register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two ways to solve the problem.

1) Sell the subscription etc. only through the App Store **in the app** (similar to Dropbox/Office etc.), i.e. there should be no links to your website, where your users have/can insert payment information. Look at the mentioned examples, how they solve this.

2) Only sell the subscription/services via the web, but **never ever** link to these pages via your app (similar to Kindle app, partially Spotify).

Your app must still be somehow (open for interpretation) functional for users without a subscription / registration.

The main issue Apple has, is that it's possible to circumvent the store and Apple's 30% cut. Just make sure that users are not able to purchase any digital products & services

> Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments

Comment: Just FYI: After 10+ reviews they went as far as to tell me that an email address could be used to start a subscription process and that should be removed too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can submit app again but you have to implement one small feature like as guest user login.

In this You will implement one UIButton it's should say "Go without login". Implement this small functionality in your app. Create one user as guest.

When user hit "Go without login" you will pass your static user id and login in the app.

I have same problem. I am create a this solution and it's work

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. The issue is they have information and/or a link in the app to an external system where the user can register/subscribe to features in the app. This isn't permitted.

Comment: Oh sorry brother. Subscribe feature is as like as In-App purchase.