# iOS app rejected due to registration

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, registration

I am stuck with one of the in-app registration rejection issue in my app and need some help on this.

The rejection information is: Your app includes an account registration/注册 feature, which is considered an access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app. Please see attached screenshots for details.

My registration page only consist of phone textfield, password textfield and verification code. I don't know why it is an access to external mechanisms for purchases. The picture url is http://a1011.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple118/v4/12/ec/1d/12ec1d3e-5684-f63e-1080-aab3111abf21/attachment-4524705789549027319Screenshot-0714-183333.png?downloadKey3=1500534691_322d75f6152c115bdb556182f679bf89

My privacy URL is http://112.74.90.144/web/serviceContent.html.   It is showed through an textView in app.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apple developers rejected- subscriptions to be used in the app - Business - 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154176/apple-developers-rejected-subscriptions-to-be-used-in-the-app-business-3-1)

Comment: Did you placed any links in that screen?

Comment: You should appeal to apple about this. At the very least they will tell you specifically whats wrong.

Comment: No, there are no any links in the screen.